# Telegram Bot Api - Как прицепить реакции к сообщению?

Tags: php, telegram

Всем привет!

Использую данную библиотеку:
https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core

Есть задача к каждому сообщению цеплять реакции, по типу, как это можно сделать с помощью @ControllerBot.

[image: Тестовая картинка 1]

Собственно с отправкой сообщений проблем не возникло:

[image: Тестовая картинка 2]

А вот как заставить работать реакции?

Если я правильно понял, то алгоритм работы реакций нужно реализовывать самостоятельно используя базу данных, хук и собственную логику инкрементации?

Или есть способ попроще?

Answer (score 1):

1. Должна быть создана таблица в БД `likes` с полями `user_id` (int), `message_id` (int), `like_button` (int).
   Пара значений `user_id` и `message_id` должна быть уникальной (но не значения по отдельности, т.к. пользователи могут лайкать разные сообщения; и так же - одно и то же сообщение могут лайкать разные пользователи):

```sql
ALTER table `message_id` add [constraint `unique_user_message`] unique index(`user_id`, `message_id`)
```

2. При нажатии на реакцию:

   1. Получаем `user_id` и `message_id` из [Update-обьекта](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) Telegram (вы получаете `Update` с `callback_query`, как найти ID пользователя и сообщение можете прочесть в документации).
   2. Получаем индекс кнопки - `like_button` в массиве клавиатуры с полученного в `Update` или с `callback_data` - как вам удобнее.
   3. Обновляем (или создаем) реакцию пользователя в БД:

   ```sql
   REPLACE into `likes`(`user_id`, `message_id`, `like_button`) values(123456, 654321, 0)
   ```

   4. Получаем массив данных со значениями `like_button` - индекс кнопки, `num` - колличество лайков:

   ```sql
   SELECT `like_button`, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM `likes` WHERE `message_id` = 654321 GROUP BY `like_button`
   ```

   5. На основе полученных данных обновляем кнопки на сообщении используя [`editMessageReplyMarkup()`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) (как обрабатывать строки расписывать уже не буду)

Если вам не принципиально, сколько раз может пользователь нажать кнопку, то можно и обойтись без БД, просто каждый раз обновляя клавиатуру и добавляя +1 к числу лайков.